MongoDB showing inconsistent ressults while querying using pymongo
I am working with pyMongo, connecting to a client's database. The specific collection, I am querying is composed by documents with a field called items, which can be an empty list or contain a series of subdocuments.
As an example, a document can look like this:

I am interested in the documents that have a non empty list of items, and for which the price is not 0.
To query, I first tried directly with the API as follows:
cursor=colecc_cotizaciones.find({"items":{"$ne":[]},"items.price":{"$ne":0},"date":{"$gte":datetime(2023,9,1),"$lt":datetime(2023,10,16)}})
i =0
for doc in cursor:
    i+=1
print(i)

For the dates specified, it only showed 42 results. I found that weird. The frequency should be greater. In order to do the analysis I created a DataFrame and put the data there with a JSON normalize:
df = pd.json_normalize(
    no_vacias, 
    record_path=['items'],  # Path to the nested list you want to flatten
    meta=[
        'id',  
        'date','city',
        'company'
    ]
)

And when I query on that DataFrame, I get a very different number of results:
df_filtered = df[(df["date"] < "2023-10-16") & (df["date"] > "2023-09-01") & (df["price"] != 0)]
df_filtered_grouped = df_filtered.groupby('id').first()
df_filtered_grouped

Notice that I am grouping by same ID. Even though I get 217 rows, not 42.
I do not quite get why I am getting different results.

1. Instead of posting an example of document as a screenshot, post it as code. Use the "Copy to Clipboard" feature of Mongo Compass and paste that as formatted code. 2. Pandas is unwinding all the items. Doing a find with "items.price":{"$ne":0} checks if any items in the list have a non-zero price and returns the documents. 3. Use an aggregation with $unwind: "$items" and then $match: "items.price":{"$ne":0} and to get the individual items, instead of the whole document which has such items.

I am guessing you are looking for "items.price" greater than 0. In such case, {"items.price": { $gt: 0 }} predicate will include non-empty arrays, and items.price has a value and greater than zero. Note that "$ne":0 can also means  a null value or non-existing price field.

@prasad_ Thank you. I used $gt and it does show the 217 ressults. Apparently, the "$gt" already unwinds the results as aneroid was suggesting. Is there anywhere in the docs where this different behaviour is signaled?
